# jquery call back function

Tags: jquery

I have a call back function as follows

```
$('#lnkClientData').click(function() {


        $('#clientdiv').slideToggle(function(){
            if($('#lnkClientData').hasClass('open'))
            {

                $('#divnext').slideToggle();
                $('#lnkClientData').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            }
            else
            {

             $('#divnext').slideToggle();
             $('#lnkClientData').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
            }
        }
        );
     });
```

I want the  `$('#divnext').slideToggle();` code to be executed before the outside  `$('#clientdiv').slideToggle()` function....
Right now the outside function gets called first....what I am trying to do is hide an anchor when a `div` slides in...but his happens before the `div` slides in...

```
  if($('#clientDiv').is(':visible'))
             {
             alert('');
               //  $('#divnext').hide();
                 //$('#clientDiv').slideToggle(); // Or whatever animation you want
             }
             else
             {
                 //$('#clientDiv').slideToggle(function() // Or whatever animation   you   want
                 //{
                   //  $('#divnext').show();
                 //});
             }
```

Comment: Can you share a demo link on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: I did what u guys mentioned but i just added a comment to the frist answer...i hope that clears out things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reorder your code then (without knowing the specifics of your slideToggle implementation, I'm assuming your parameter is a callback when the slide is finished)

```
 $('#divnext').slideToggle(function()
 {
     // Code here executes after slide is finished but before clientdiv starts
     $('#clientdiv').slideToggle(function()
     {
          // Code here executes after both slides are done
     });
 });
```

EDIT:

In your situation, simply using one slideToggle method to show / hide the client div is not the best idea.

```
 if($('#clientDiv').is(':visible'))
 {
     $('#yourLink').hide();
     $('#clientDiv').slideDown(); // Or whatever animation you want
 }
 else
 {
     $('#clientDiv').slideUp(function() // Or whatever animation you want
     {
         $('#yourLink').show();
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks...its reallly close to what I wanted...but now when the outer div slides out....the inner div appears before the div opens....let me explain...i have a div...and a anchor name "next" inside the div...when someone opens the div...this next anchor should appear after the whole div opens and when someone closes the div the next anchor should dissapear before the div closes....

Comment: Then all you need to do is initially have the div hidden. When the clientDiv finished its toggle, simply invoke `$('#yourLink').show()` or `hide()` depending on it's visibility.

Comment: I am confused..can you explain a buit more...the main div is the client and when it finishes toggle I should display or hide the link...and also that this hide and show should be outside the call back function of the toggle function....am i right??

Comment: I will try and get back to you if have any problem....ill add another comment...but i know ill be able to do it...Thanks alot man

Comment: See my question i am going to edit it...i am doing what you did after the edit part.....but uit doesnt seems to raise the alert...plz refer to my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Code code is setup to toggle the lnkClientData then when that is done toggle the clientdiv, if you swap them around ie:

```
$('#divnext').click(function() {
    $('#clientdiv').slideToggle(function(){
        if($('#lnkClientData').hasClass('open'))
        {

            $('#lnkClientData').slideToggle();
            $('#lnkClientData').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        }
        else
        {

         $('#lnkClientData').slideToggle();
         $('#lnkClientData').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
        }
    }
    );
 });
```